# Pandas shift dataframe if date is found in string column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that should have 7 columns. It has 9 columns instead, that's because some rows are shifted to the right to one or two columns.

I need to make some order in my df. I have this elements:

- the first two columns are always fine, but the second one could be null (that is also fine);
- the third column is a date, could be null due to the shift to the next column or because it's actually null
- the fourth column is a name of a city, and sometimes it contains the date from column 3. Sometimes is null
- fifth column has the same behaviour as the fourth
- last two columns are fine (even if some rows are shifted)

Now, the approach that I was thinking is to check in column 4 for values that could be converted into date and, if found, shift that row from that column of one space to the left (not the entire row, because the first two columns are fine). Then I would repeat with a check in the fifth column.

code up until now (provided by chatGPT)

```
df['names'], df['dates'] = df['fourth column'].str.split(' ', 1).str
```

It successfully create a column with only the names, but it fails in creating the dates one. all of the results are null.

Other approach with no results:

```
des_col= 'fourth'

col_index= df.columns.get_loc(des_col)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if pd.api.types.is_datetime64_any_dtype(row[des_col]):
        df.iloc[index, col_index:] = row.iloc[col_index:].shift(-1)
```

sample: (tt is some text)
In this case rows 0 and 2 are good, while 1 and 3 should be shifted to the left from column 3:

```
1 2 3           4           5   6   7  na1  na2
A E 2026-02-27  Torino      tt  tt  tt NaN  NaN
Z G NaN         1964-06-22  tt  tt  tt tt   NaN
Z G NaN         NaT         tt  tt  tt NaN  NaN
Z F NaN         1961-04-26  tt  tt  tt NaN  NaN
```

I made some progress by doing so:

```
# first I've created a column with only the dates from column 4
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['4], errors='coerce')

#Then I assign the value at column 3, if it's not null, and then I shift

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if pd.notnull(row['date']):
        df.iloc[index, df.columns.get_loc('3')] = row['date']
        df.iloc[index, df.columns.get_loc('3'):] = row.iloc[df.columns.get_loc('3'):].shift(-1)
```

The problem here is that now the df is shifted, but there are still some rows not shifted due to the fact that they don't belong to the previous case.

So the question now is how do I shift to the left the rows that still have column 'na1' populated, until I find an empty column?

```
1 2 3           4   5   6   7  na1  na2
Z G 1964-06-22 NaN  tt  tt  tt tt   NaN

#expected output:
1 2 3           4   5   6   7  na1  na2
Z G 1964-06-22  tt  tt  tt  tt NaN  NaN
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you maybe provide a sample dataframe with a few rows? Does the fifth column contain cities as well that are shifted? With a sample it might be clearer how it adds up to 9 columns.

Comment: For clarity, show all four expected rows.